# Flow control between ESP32 and RS323 device

Tags: serial, communication, esp32, rs232

I'm trying to communicate an RS232 device with an ESP32 (Heltec Wifi/LoRa 32 v2) my problem is that I don't receive any response from the device, doing some research, I'm thinking that the trouble can be the flow control because I don't use these pins and the modules I've used neither have these pins. Do you know a way to, at least, solder the DB9 pins to have a sort of flow control to communicate the devices?

Comment: What kind of device are you trying to communicate with?

Comment: Also: do you use a TTL->RS232 converter?

Comment: This can only be answered by looking at the data sheet of "the RS232 device". You can emulate RTS/CTS flow control by connecting them to two unused GPIO pins and then taking care of them in your own code while sending data back and forth. Also, a real RS232 interface communicates on signal levels between 3 and 15V, so if you are not absolutely sure that "the RS232 device" answers on a signal level of less than 3.6V, you will absolutely need a level shifter. Better use a dedicated RS232 shield for that -- which is the only answer I can give from the information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ESP-IDF calls to setup your UART correctly for hardware serial communication on pin 4 and 5 (and perhaps also other pins).

In the sample below, you just have to:

- assign `UART_CLIENT_RTS` and `UART_CLIENT_CTS` to the pins of your need
- change `uart_config_t` to whichever parameters are relevant for your RS232 device
- set `flow_ctrl` to `UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_RTS`, `UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_CTS`, `UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_CTS_RTS` or `UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_MAX`

```
    #define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

    #define UART_CLIENT_TXD  (GPIO_NUM_4)
    #define UART_CLIENT_RXD  (GPIO_NUM_5)
    #define UART_CLIENT_RTS  (GPIO_NUM_?) // Set this
    #define UART_CLIENT_CTS  (GPIO_NUM_?) // Set this
    
    uart_port_t uartNum = UART_NUM_1;

    uart_config_t uart_config = { // Set this
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity    = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_CTS_RTS
    };
        
    uart_param_config(uartNum, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(uartNum, UART_CLIENT_TXD, UART_CLIENT_RXD, UART_CLIENT_RTS, UART_CLIENT_CTS);
    uart_driver_install(uartNum, BUFFER_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
```

Communication can be done with the various `uart_write_*` and `uart_read_*` methods as defined in the [documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/uart.html).